# try to print one statement after fork in c

Tags: c, unix, fork, system-calls

I want my ouput to be

```
456
123
```

But my output is

```
456
123
123
```

```
int status;
int pid = fork();
if (pid == 0){
    char* s1 = "4 5 6\n";
    printf("%s", s1);
}
wait(&status);
char* s2 = "1 2 3\n";
printf("%s", s2);
```

Comment: What do you think `fork` does that would explain this output?

Comment: Use [fflush(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html) after the first `printf`. Use [strace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) to understand what is happenning

Comment: You print `1 2 3` in both parent and the child.

Comment: Sidenote: Precision matters.Your output is not `456...` but `4 5 6 ...` .

Answer (score 1):

```
char* s2 = "1 2 3\n";
printf("%s", s2);
```

Since this print takes place outside of any checks, and since the forked process picks up where the `fork` call happened, both processes will reach and execute that print.

If you only want it to be printed by the parent, you need to manually ensure that with a separate check:

```
if (pid == 0){  // This block will only be entered by the child process
    char* s1 = "4 5 6\n";
    printf("%s", s1);

} else if (pid > 0) {  // This block will only be entered by the parent process
    wait(&status);
    char* s2 = "1 2 3\n";  
    printf("%s", s2);

} else {
    // Handle errors
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `char* s2 = "1 2 3\n"; printf("%s", s2);` is placed outside the `if` statement's body, the parent process will also print `"1 2 3\n"`.

Place

```
char* s2 = "1 2 3\n";
printf("%s", s2);
```

or simplified

```
puts("1 2 3");
```

(Note: `puts()` automatically appends a newline character)

inside of the `if` statement´s body:

```
int status;
int pid = fork();
if (pid == 0) {
    puts("4 5 6");
    puts("1 2 3");
}
wait(&status);
```

to only let the child process print `"1 2 3\n"`.

---

Beside that:

If you only want your output to be

```
4 5 6
1 2 3
```

you don´t need to use `fork()`.

Just use `printf("%s","4 5 6\n1 2 3");`.

Comment: You could have also said "Drop your whole program and do `printf("456 123");` instead."

Comment: @Ctx You might be laughing but that was one of my thoughts indeed, although single argument `printf()` is dangerous. (Well, not real to turn that into answer). Sorry, updated explanation. But as the question had no explanation my answer had so, too.

Comment: _"You might be laughing"_ He he ;)

Comment: @Ctx I give it a try indeed. Question should really include more details. I voted to close.